# Google Analytics crash report iOS - Not clear what the error

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, crash-reports, generic-exception, google-analytics-sdk

I'm encountering some crash in my iOS application.
I use Google Analytics SDK to intercept crashes on clients devices. But the problem is the content of the crashlog.

```
NSGenericException Trace: <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> <redacted> CFRunLoopRunSpecific CFRunLoopRunInM
```

I don't have more information about the error. If someone know what it speaks about, it would be much appreciated.

***Edit*** : I can't use other SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PLCrashReporter`. It gives you more information about crashes and send an email to your mail accounts. For more information check below link

https://www.plcrashreporter.org

Comment: Thanks for the proposition but I can't use other SDK. It's my company choice.